# How to verify Java Bytecode before injecting into the JVM?

Tags: java, bytecode, javassist, java-bytecode-asm, bcel

I'm trying to verify "on the fly" generated bytecode!

I already had several attempts, one attempt was to compile my classes in runtime with the eclipse compiler another was to compile from memory as mentioned here:

[Compile From Memory](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/CompilingfromMemory.htm)

First results looked okay but I'm still not a 100% sure if the verification process is truly valid according to the JAVA 6 guidelines and security measurements as well to normal OOP Models.

Any better way on how to verify bytecode?

Comment: how is this related to [assembly]? I guess you meant [java-bytecode-asm], right?

Comment: What do you mean by "verify"? Do you mean for instance type-check?

Comment: I never used the assembly tag, dont know why this was there...

Comment: Why I mean with verify is that I need to secure that there are no schematic problems like wrong inheritance and stuff, so I just need to secure that my bytecode does not break with java 6 rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the generated bytecode using a standard class loader, the bytecode verifier of the JVM will verify (make sure it type checks, never falls of the "edge" of a method and so on) the bytecode for you.

Comment: okay, it works. But is there a way to get better exceptions/error reports? Or to get information why verification failed?

Comment: Not that I know of. Despite a lot of bytecode hacking I've never found a good way to debug such type of problems.

Comment: @Evils The JVM doesn't provide helpful error messages for verification failure. You're only options are to either recompile the JVM or use a different tool. I've actually written one myself but there are probably other tools out there that could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the class verifier provided by the ASM toolkit](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q4). That does not require actually loading the classes by the JVM, and gives you more detailed verification error reports.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11950712)